# Implementing customised loss function in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

I am new to Keras and wanted to implement a loss function as shown in the figure:

[image: Loss function].

In the function, h is the output of the neural network, X is a data matrix and ψ is a matrix, such that ψ[i,j] = 1 iff X[i,j]'s value exists or else it is 0. The dot product used is Hadamard dot product and Frobenius norm is used. How can this loss function be implemented in Keras (with TensorFlow as backend) using python ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You just need to define a python `def` method. You need to carry out all the calculations using K which is `from tensorflow.keras.backend import K`

Comment: That means creating a function which will take y_pred and y_true as parameters, but since values of ψ are dependent on the (i,j) of the matrix (dependent on the arrangement of data in data matrix), how am I supposed to know the order in which input is being fed? Please let me know if you didn't understand my doubt !

Comment: Hi Ruckus, this is one year later, but if it can still help you, I was just looking for a similar thing. Maybe https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/549 can give an idea.